# Error - can't add new key into hash during iteration

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby and am playing around with the gem to access some of the data from the Guardian UKs open platform - `contentapi-ruby`.

When running a test example I keep getting the error:

```
(TestSearchContent): RuntimeError: can't add a new key into hash during iteration.
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? What exactly does this error mean?

My code:

```
 require 'guardian-content'

 articles = GuardianContent::Content.search("Obama")

 articles.each do |article|
    puts article.title
    puts article.url
 end
```

Comment: Did you think to ... look up that error?

Comment: @BrianRoach, hah! I just got this same error (doing something completely unrelated) and the first thing I did was google it. This question on SO is the top-ranked result... So your advice is outdated -- "looking up that error" results in this same page.

Comment: Regarding my actual reason for googling this: For anyone that got here by running "inspect" on Rack environment variable see: https://github.com/rack/rack/issues/241

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there's a bug in the library. You can fix it by applying this patch:

https://github.com/chrsgrrtt/contentapi-ruby/commit/46326bce44177d1b8287a4a7167c895531eac25a

Comment: fgb - Tx very much for the help!