# can't add a new key into hash during iteration

Tags: ruby, mongoid

Can anyone explain to me what exactly mean this runtime exception?

```
can't add a new key into hash during iteration
```

I have this error in this piece of code (Im using Mongoid):

```
new_item_entries = []

item.entries.each do |entry|
  new_item_entries << ItemEntry.new(name: entry.field) # exception here
end  

self.entries = new_item_entries
self.save
```

But this exception burns in NOT any cases! In my Rspec test I have 3 of 70 test fails with this exception. Most of tests use code above.

Comment: Where does that `ItemEntry` come from?

Comment: Its sample code, but logic is correct.

Comment: Well, I can't see the problem, given the information you provided. Should work. :)

Comment: Yep its my problem too :) Code is very simple.. This exception confuse me. I just dont know how avoid this..

Comment: You say it's sample code - does that exact code produce an exception on your machine ?

Comment: which version of ruby are you using..?

Comment: so as you say, this code executes correctly in maxm scenarios..

Comment: side note: don't use each like that! this is a map.

Comment: im using 1.9.3. what different between map and each? Also I think i found solution. in my code while i iterate mongoid criteria (item.entries) and item == entry, mongoid try to modify "item" hash, but in 1.9.3 this throws exception

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998355/error-cant-add-new-key-into-hash-during-iteration suggests that it is a library error